# How to filter kendo grid column value with dynamic filter function

Tags: kendo-ui

I would like to be able to filter kendo grid column which has dropdown data using following code

```
filter: [{
        "field": "id_person",
        "operator": "eq",
        "value": 4
   }]
```

In grid, field id_person is dropdown and has value something like this

```
id_person : {VALUE: "4", DESCRIPTION: "Keval"}
```

But filter is not working for that particular column because it has dropdown inside grid.
How to achieve this ? please help.

Demo link: 
https://dojo.telerik.com/uvawonIh

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.filterable.cell#columnsfilterablecelltemplate

Comment: The demo link is not as per your problem statement. Can you please share the sample code as per your problem statement ?

Answer (score 0):

The `id` field in your Dojo is **not** `id_person`, so filtering will **not** work when the filter criteria parameters specify `"field":"id_person"`.

I am presuming you want to apply a filter to the grid data source from outside the grid itself, such as when a non-grid button is clicked.

Suppose your html has

```
<button id="filter" type="button">Filter</button>
```

then your jQuery ready function might have this statement within

```
  $("#filter").kendoButton({
    click: function(e) {

      var filterParameters =
        [{
          "field": "id",
          "operator": "eq",
          "value": 2
        }]
      ;

      $("#grid")
      .data("kendoGrid")
      .dataSource
      .filter(filterParameters)
      ;
    }
  });
```

See modified [Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/AgODiTan/4) and [DataSource filter method docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/filter)